# php curl post large data

Tags: php, post, curl, nginx

I'm using php5-curl to post large data around 1M.
When I receive the post data. It correct sometimes, but lost some data sometimes.
e.g
I post to

```
http://www.example.com/upload  
post data  
md5=769ab98787e897f89e&data={large data and urlencode}
```

md5 field is the data's md5.
But when I receive the data and calc the md5. it incorrect sometimes.

I'm running nginx as a web server and php-fpm as FastCGI.
And I have add

```
 client_max_body_size 10m;
```

to nginx.conf

Comment: Would it be possible for `example.com` to use CURL, make a `GET` request and download the data?

Comment: example.com is just for example. I'm using my own domain. I can post the data to the server correctly. But sometimes it fail. So I think the data is too large.

Comment: I figured `example.com` was not the domain your working with. Could you use that domain to download the data rather than have the other server upload it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably use binary data with [urlencode()](http://www.php.net/urlencode).
Try use [base64_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) before.

> This encoding is designed to make binary data survive transport
>   through transport layers that are not 8-bit clean.
>
> Note: Base64-encoded data takes about 33% more space than the original
>   data.